# A-frame with lottie json

Tags: aframe

i'm exploring with AR environment and would like to animate my animation in lottie json instead of gltf, is it possible to map a lottie json to an a-frame environment? I saw someone did it successfully in three.js, but i couldn't seem to get the json to load.

Comment: do you have an example with the lottie animation (not in ar.js, pure aframe)

Comment: i have the lottie json file, found an example in fiddle that does that in three.js (https://jsfiddle.net/h9emygLj/) but i'm not sure how to replicate that in a-frame

Comment: I would do it a bit differently than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311314/aframe-not-rendering-lottie-json-texture-mapped-to-canvas-but-works-in-three-js/66313477#66313477), I could try to make a full answer once i have a while