# User painting on a canvas within A-Frame

Tags: html5-canvas, aframe

I have an A-Frame scene that contains, among others, a `<canvas>` element that is the material source for a 3D scene object. I can paint on the canvas programmatically, and it shows up as texture. So far, so good.

However, I'd now also like to enable the user to paint something on the canvas using the controllers. I have added two raycasters/controls:

```xml
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: left"  raycaster="objects: table2"></a-entity>
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: table2"></a-entity>
```

And on the `table2` object, I have added a `raycaster-listen` mixin as described in https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/raycaster.html#listening-for-raycaster-intersection-data-change.

This works in so far as I get the console log entries with the world coordinates of the intersection point, but I'm absolutely stuck at how to get from the world coordinates back to the canvas coordinates I need to actually paint in the right spot.

In addition, it seems no canvas draw commands I issue in the `raycaster-listen` tick callback actually have any visible effect (regardless of coordinates).

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I figured it out the next day

> [...] I'm absolutely stuck at how to get from the world coordinates back to the canvas coordinates I need to actually paint in the right spot.

Solution found at https://discourse.threejs.org/t/convert-camera-frustrum-to-uv-coordinate-on-texture/16791/2 - just use `intersection.uv` which actually contains the normalized texture coordinates of the intersection point. Scale by canvas width/height and you're done.

> [...] it seems no canvas draw commands I issue in the `raycaster-listen` tick callback actually have any visible effect.

Solution found at [aframe not rendering lottie json texture mapped to canvas but works in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311314/aframe-not-rendering-lottie-json-texture-mapped-to-canvas-but-works-in-three-js/66313477#66313477) - set `texture.needsUpdate = true;` in the tick callback after drawing on the canvas.